# Random Substitution Cipher (Python)

Tags: python, encryption, random, substitution

I'm writing a random substitution cipher, and it works well when being used to write regular sentences. However, when I try to test 'abbcccddddeeeee', I will get something back like 'G H H I I I J J J J K K K K K'. How can I change my code so that either 'key' or 'vari' changes for each letter in the cycle yet stays the same so that no letter corresponds to more than one other letter?

```
import random
intext = raw_input("Enter a message to encrypt: ")
intext = intext.upper()
key = random.randint(0,27)
vari = random.randint(0,27)
def randomsub(intext):
    outtext = []
    intext = intext.upper()
    for c in intext:
        num = ord(c)
        if num >= ord('A') and num <= ord('Z'):
            num = num - ord('A')
            num = num + (key + vari) % 26
            num += ord('A')
            outtext.append(chr(num))
    return ' '.join(outtext)
print randomsub(intext)
```

Comment: What's wrong with that result you're getting?

Comment: Have you put any thought into how decryption is supposed to work, either for the way your code is now or the way you want your code to be?

Comment: mmm, like the [enigma machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_machine)?

Comment: @StefanPochmann If it were to work like a proper rsc, the result would be something like GOOZZZIIIIAAAAA; the letters shouldn't be in direct sequence

Comment: @user2357112 There doesn't need to be decryption, just encryption.

Comment: @DoNotPutMeInABox: That is fundamentally not encryption, then. Encryption *must* be decryptable. If it's not decryptable, you might as well completely ignore the input and just generate a bunch of random bytes for output.

Comment: @user2357112 What I meant is that I don't need to program a decryption program. Yes, it has to be decryptable, but I don't have the skills to program one for a random substitution cipher.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have both `key` and `vari`, but the randomness should be inside your function, and at least one of the calls to `randint` should be inside the loop.  I'd recommend making `key` a user-provided input, and using it to seed `random`.  That way, with the same text and the same key, you get the same output, but duplicate letters in the text will vary in the result.  Last, but not least, if you want the output to be letters you need to expand the parentheses where you add `key` and `vari` to include `num`, i.e.,  `num = (num + vari) % 26` if you switch to using `key` as I suggested.

Comment: When I implemented your suggestion, I got an answer like "R T V J R D M W I S W W R F P", which is random, but what I need is a solution where if I substitute G for A, all instances of A need to be G. Also, what do you mean by "seed random"?

Comment: @DoNotPutMeInABox What do I mean by "seed random?" [Documentation is your friend](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.seed).  The result of re-using a seed value when you run your program is that the results will vary, but are completely reproducible.  For encryption purposes, that's way better than having all 'A's map to the letter on the output side.  A good cryptologist would very quickly pick up on letter frequencies for English, but having the letter 'E' map to 'X', 'A', 'W',... depending on where you are in the message will make it much more challenging.